# Smoking 3lb Pork Butt

Tags: pork, smoking

I'm smoking a small 3lb pork butt we picked up at the farmer's market. If I plan on cooking it at 225 degrees, how long do you think it will take to get to an internal temp of 160? That's when I plan on wrapping it in foil before getting it to an internal temp of 190. Thanks for helping out a newbie!

Comment: Given that we don't know whether or not you are using a smoker, or if you are getting the job done in a regular oven with liquid smoke, and we don't know the idiosyncrasies of either one (they almost all have personalities of their own), I'm thinking you would be better served by picking up a meat thermometer than by hoping your smoker or oven behaves exactly as somebody else's does. Thermometers are not expensive and can be found at pretty well any store that sells kitchenware and utensils.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to predict when you will reach your foiling target, but the general rule of thumb for pulled pork at your stated cooking temperature is about 1.5 hours per pound, with some general allowances for margin of error.

I would plan on the entire cook taking about 5-6 hours, but be ready for it to be finished in 4. At about 3 hours, start checking temperatures to determine when you will want to foil your roast.

Final note: If your intent is to make pulled pork, do NOT assume that it is done just because it is at 190f. Your thermometer probe should slide in and out of the meat with virtually zero resistance.